# How to force visual studio to automatically increase the build number?

Tags: c#, version-control, assemblies

I modified the AssemblyInfo.cs file

At the end of the file

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.6.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

And I assumed that now the assembly version will change automatically when the application is compiled. But no. The version is frozen at 0.6.8717 and is not increasing further.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How can you check that? Do you know difference between AssemblyVersion (Product version) VS AssemblyFileVersion (File version)?

Comment: I know this because I write it in the title of the form. 
`Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
Text = Text + " " + version.Major + "." + version.Minor + " (build " + version.Build + ")";`

Comment: Today 0.6.8717 changed to 0.6.8718. Does the build number only change once a day?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you just use `AssemblyVersion` only 3 digit. That's why it only changes once a day. Try to update with this code

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.6.*.*")]
```

The third number (the build number) is the number of days since 2000-01-01.
The fourth number (the revision number) is the number of seconds since midnight divided by 2.

Here is [a sample project about increasing `AssemblyVersion` automatically](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31236/How-To-Update-Assembly-Version-Number-Automaticall).

Comment: I can't add the 4th number. Studio shows error

Error CS7034 The specified version string does not match the required format - major number[.minor number[.build[.revision]]].